# How to apply filters on the basis of latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to apply filters on the basis of latitude and longitude. There is a table having column id, title, latitude, longitude (MySql) & I want to get the results in the range of 4 km as I am providing latitude and longitude of my current location.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE (latitude = 26.85005 AND longitude = 26.85393) AND (longitude = 80.94964 AND longitude = 80.96595) HAVING acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(latitude) + cos(1.3963) * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude - (-0.6981))) <= 0.1570
```

Comment: Could you also provide us with your code so we can help you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, that is possible.

```
SELECT a.title,
   111.111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.Latitude)), 1.0))) AS distance_in_km
  FROM table AS a
  JOIN table AS b ON a.id <> b.id
  HAVING distance_in_km <= 4
```

Here, `HAVING distance_in_km <= 4` 4 is the KM range.

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT 
   111.111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(a.latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude - b.longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude)), 1.0))) AS distance_in_km
  FROM ads AS a HAVING distance_in_km <= 4 LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'b.Latitude' in 'field list'

Comment: how can i select all the columns?

Comment: your answer is working himanshu but How can I select all the columns

Comment: @PriyaSrivastava, did you get all the columns?

Comment: I want to get all the columns but SELECT title, 111.111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(COS(RADIANS(a.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.Longitude - b.Longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(a.Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(b.Latitude)), 1.0))) AS distance_in_km FROM ads AS a JOIN ads AS b ON a.id <> b.id HAVING distance_in_km <= 10

Comment: Check the change, I added `a.title` column in my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for marking my answer and voting it up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finding locations nearby with MySQL

Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

Table Structure :

id,title,lat,lng

NOTE - Here latitude = 37 & longitude = -122. So you just pass your own.

```
 SELECT id, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * 
 cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
 cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) +
 sin( radians(37) ) * 
 sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
 AS distance FROM your_table_name HAVING
 distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

`3959 - Miles = 6371 - Kilometers`

Comment: SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(80.96595) ) + sin( radians(26.85393) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ads HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20

Comment: giving empty result set while the values longitude & latitude exist in my table

Comment: can you remove the `limit` parameter once?

Comment: and also replace 3959 with 6371 as you are filtering on kilometers instead of miles

Comment: and in your first line of query - `SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) ` replace 37 with your latitude i.e. `26.85393`

Answer (score 0):

```
$latitude='28.5410297';//yours latitude
$longitude='-81.37857600000001';//yours longitude
SELECT *,(((acos(sin((" . $latitude . "*pi()/180)) * sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((" . $latitude . "*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((" . $longitude . "- `Longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance from table_name having distance < 4 ORDER BY distance ASC"
```